# How can I debug " SyntaxError: expected expression, got ',' "

Tags: javascript

I keep on getting the following error message SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

on my firebug console. All it shoes is a line number on my jquery.js file but I have no idea on where the error is on my actual code.

Would anyone have an idea on how I can debug the error message? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you post your code we could help you somehow.

Comment: To clarify what I think the OP is asking... It sounds like the question is "When my browser console gives me a line number in jQuery or another 3rd party library, how can I trace it back to where my code invoked it so I can debug my code?"  I suspect that if there's a *lot* of code, posting *all* of it here wouldn't be much use.  It sounds like the OP is asking how to use the browser debugging tools for a specific purpose, not asking what's wrong with his code.

Comment: @David Yes exactly. Do you recommend using FireBug for that?

Comment: @json2022, If you use Google Chrome, my answer below is covers how to do it in Chrome. If you use Firefox, then Firebug is for you, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Unless we see your code we won't be able to help much.

But you could always test your code at http://www.jslint.com/

EDIT: You could also [inspect the call stack](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#call-stack-panel) so as to trace where it is being invoked.

[image]